# Flutter translate app with String Extension without the need of context like in Swift

Tags: swift, string, flutter, localization

I would like to localize my `Flutter` app. In `Swift` I am using this `String-Extension`:

```
func localized() -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(
        self,
        tableName: "Localizable",
        bundle: .main,
        value: self,
        comment: self)
}
```

My `Localizable-File` would like this:

```
"Hello World" = "Hallo Welt";
```

And I could use the helper-function like this:

With this I can simply call `let testString = "Hello World".localized()`.

I would like to have the same in Flutter but can not make it work, since I always need a `context`. Does anyone know if there is a way to copy this `Swift` version for `Flutter`? Couldn't find anything on this..

Answer (score 0):

Use this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/i18n_extension

Use it like this:

```
var testString = "Hello World".i18n;
```

Note: I am one of the authors of this package.